# JavaScript code execution delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
function append(what) {
    $("#drawer").append(what);
}

function outerHtml(o) {
    return $("<div />").append($(o).clone()).html();
}

var allPixel = [];

$(".pix").each(function() {
    allPixel.push(outerHtml($(this)));
});

$("#drawer").empty();

var index;

for (index = 0; index < allPixel.length; index++) {
    pixel = allPixel[index];
    setTimeout(append(pixel), 100);
}
```

I have a Container (`#drawer`) that is full of many div elements. In this function the HTML of each of these div elements gets saved in an array individually. When its done doing that the div element gets cleared.

In the Array `allPixel` are now all div elements. I want it so that each div element gets added to `#drawer` with a delay of 100ms.

**Problem:**

If I run this function nothing happens (the divs are not disappearing/ appearing). What did I do wrong?

If anything is unclear feel free to let me know and I will edit my question.

**Question aswered... See it in action: https://wiese2.lima-city.de/test/**

Comment: Create a JsFiddle, or add executable code here please

Comment: Ok, first of all, your `setTimeout` call is wrong, the first argument should be a function not a function call. Secondly, do you want to add all pixels at the same time after 100ms or each pixel to be added after 100ms of adding the previous one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are invoking the method invoking immediately and passing its return value i.e. `undefined` to [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout).

You can set additional parameters to be passed to `append` function when timer expires to  [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) method.

*Use*

```
setTimeout(append, 100 * (i + 1), pixel);
```

Additionally you also need to increase timer based on element index

Comment: Thank you so much! Now it works perfectly! (I used "setTimeout(append, 10*index, pixel)")